# <Flutter> how to share same sqlite database between different apps?

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, sqlite

i'm trainee developer.

now, i'm developing the app with flutter.

For storing data, i store the data in sqlite.

while making app, i have a question about sqlite.

To solve this problem, i have tried searching all sites(stackoverflow,github,etc...). But i can't find some answer.

can i use same sqlite database in different apps?
(different app mean user1's app and user2's app)

if it can share between different apps, if you can, plz give me some advise about how to use same sqlite database both in android and IOS.

thank u for reading.

Comment: As far as I know you can't access another sqllite db from your app. They are bind to your app. You can just use some external db like firebase

Comment: You might be able to do that, look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.

Comment: thank u so much about answers!!